# Protecting or Extending Pre-Settled Status

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizens, brexit

I have European Citizenship and I was in UK for three months until 27 August 2019. Then I returned back to the Turkey to continue studying. When my pre-settled status was approved, the date was February  2020. It says it is valid till February 2025. But I have not had a chance to go to the UK due to the corona virus. Now I want to go to the UK again this Summer and I am not sure whether my pre-settled status is still valid or not.
Also I want to ask if I have chance to move to the UK after graduating (2023) from my university in Turkey? I mean, can I protect or extend my pre-settled status if I've been out of the UK for study?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/what-settled-and-presettled-status-means

Comment: What European citizenship do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You have pre-settled status until Feb 2025. You lose your pre-settled status if you leave the UK for more than two years, so you need to return to the UK before Aug. 2021. Whether a holiday in the summer is enough to keep pre-settled status will depend on politics, but living in the UK will be much more promising. And you can’t get settled status if you left for more than 6 months (possibly 12 months for important reasons), so since you left almost 14 months ago, you shouldn’t be able to get settled status and would have to leave Feb. 2025.

Someone more knowledgeable might know what your chances of getting a working visa are, but EU citizenship won’t help you after Feb 2025.

So in total: Live in the UK before Aug 2021 and before Aug 2023 for a few months at least to keep pre-settled status. Then inquire about getting a working visa after Feb 2025.

Comment: I think the last sentence would be clearer as "Well before you have to leave the UK in Feb. 2025, inquire about getting a working visa so you can stay in the UK after Feb 2025.

Comment: Interestingly, I couldn’t find anything about getting a work visa _while you still have presettled status and don’t need it yet_, when you know already the exact date when you lose it. I think it would be quite typical for the mental giants running the UK to have never given this a thought.